# How intelligent is SQL Server Mirroring?

Tags: sql, sql-server, disaster-recovery, database-mirroring

While working on my current development product I have setup SQL server mirroring between the primary data center and the secondary data center.  In the primary data center the SQL .mdf and .ldf files are stored on the SAN.

Now admittedly it should be very unlikely for us to lose the SAN but if for example the connection to the SAN was lost and the database integrity was lost.  Would the mirroring still happen?  I.e. would SQL now mirror the broken database and now both are equally broken?

From googling its not clear when mirroring will and will not happen so I was hoping that the community may be able to share some of there experiences.

I also have backup schedules setup which would be a final fail safe but realistically I would hope that the mirrored database would be our quickest way to bring everything back online.

In this scenario at present there is no witness server in the mirroring process although with the benefits of automatic failover I am thinking of adding one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as mirroring corruption between PRIMARY and SECONDARY goes: unfortunately, it depends.  If the corruption is immediate and physical, then not *normally* -- the corruption is typically picked up by checks done at the end of the transaction and rolled back.

However, a database can exist in a corrupted state for some time before anything realises it is corrupted.  If the underlying data pages are not touched, the engine never has cause to check them.  So it is possible that underlying storage issues may mean that either database can become corrupted and you won't know until you attmept to access the affected pages.  Traditionally, this would be a write operation, since your client connection will only read from the current active database (and not the partner).

This is why it is important to perform regular maintenance checks on your databases (e.g. `DBCC CHECKDB`).  This becomes harder in a mirrored environment because only PRIMARY can typically be checked, so you really have to induce a manual failover to test your SECONDARY (unless you are running Enterprise, where you *might* be able to snapshot the mirror and check that -- I've not tried).

Starting with SQL Server 2008, the engine will attempt something called Automatic Page Repair, where it tries to automatically recover corrupted pages it encounters during the mirroring process.  You should probably keep an eye on [sys.dm_db_mirroring_auto_page_repair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677259%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) if this is something you are worried about.

If it is logical corruption, where the wrong data is entered, this will push across to SECONDARY without any means of stopping it.

However, I should point out that your approach might leave you with other issues.  Mirroring isn't backup.  And mirroring isn't great over WAN links.

In synchronous mode, it receives the client request, then writes to PRIMARY, then writes to SECONDARY, gets the OK back from SECONDARY and then sends an OK back to the client.  If it can't write to SECONDARY, or doesn't get the response from SECONDARY, it rolls back the operation on PRIMARY (even though it was successful) and sends a failure back to the client.

A failing WAN link (even temporarily) can cause PRIMARY to choose not to accept connections (because it can't see SECONDARY).  A failover mid-connection can leave you in an invalid logical data state, so make sure your transactions are sound.

With a WITNESS server, this can be a little more robust -- placing the witness server alongside PRIMARY in the same LAN allows WITNESS and PRIMARY to form quorum and agree that PRIMARY is still working, even though it can't see SECONDARY (thus not locking you out of a perfectly functioning database).

Instead, over my slower site-to-site links, I prefer to use log shipping between PRIMARY and SECONDARY.  With a bit of effort I can control the transport between sites so as to rate-limit over the WAN link and it is possible keep the log-shipped SECONDARY in a single-user standby mode.  This allows me to run the standard `DBCC CHECKDB` commands against SECONDARY, as well as also querying the SECONDARY for data reconcilliation purposes, too.  I can also put a delay on the restoration, too, so I have some leeway to failover *before* a major logical data error reaches the SECONDARY (although that really depends on the RDO).

If I have a high-availability requirement, I might put in mirroring at the main site only -- i.e. two servers + witness.  The relatively-quick few-second automatic failover time provided by the witnessed environment has saved me a few late-night calls, in the past.

Hope this helps.

J.